Configuring Azure Workload Identity for KEDA with Azure Event Hub in Azure Container Apps (with Bicep)
I'm attempting to set up autoscaling for an Azure Container App using the Event-Hub KEDA scaler. The application needs to authenticate to Azure Event Hub using a user-managed identity. I've understood that KEDA supports Azure workload identity for this purpose, but I'm having trouble configuring it correctly, especially the identityId for the workload identity within the scaling rule.
From my research and existing documentation (e.g., KEDA docs, Azure samples), I've found that Azure supports both pod identity and workload identity for such scenarios, but detailed examples for Azure Container Apps are scarce.
Here's a snippet of my Bicep template where I'm trying to set up the scaling rule:
resource app 'Microsoft.App/containerApps@2022-03-01' = {
  identity: {
    type: 'UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      '${managedIdentity.id}': {}
    }
  }
  properties: {
    // Omitted for brevity...
    template: {
      // Omitted for brevity...
      scale: {
        rules: [
          {
            name: 'eh-keda-scale',
            custom: {
              type: 'azure-eventhub'
              metadata: {
                consumerGroup: containerAppName,
                unprocessedEventThreshold: '64',
                // Possibly needed according to the Keda event-hub docs?
                eventHubNamespace: eventHubNamespace,
                eventHubName: eventHubName,
                // Attempt to configure workload identity
                // Unsure how to properly specify `identityId` here
              },
              auth: [
                {
                  secretRef: 'clientIdentitySecret',
                  triggerParameter: 'identityId'
                  // How should `identityId` be configured for workload identity?
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}


Here is the reference I've used.
https://github.com/kedacore/sample-dotnet-worker-servicebus-queue/?tab=readme-ov-file
https://keda.sh/docs/2.13/scalers/azure-event-hub/
Unfortunately, the documentation is not clear on HOW to configure the workload identity, and in particular how and where to configure the identityId. There's some clues here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/scale-app?pivots=azure-resource-manager#example-2
But nothing concrete for a pod or workload identity. The Bicep reference for the resource type is:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.app/2022-03-01/containerapps?pivots=deployment-language-bicep

Apparently this is not supported at the time of writing.

Using managed identities in scale rules isn't supported. You'll still
need to include the connection string or key in the secretRef of the
scaling rule.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/managed-identity?tabs=portal%2Cdotnet#limitations
I'm going to work around it by fetching the number of partitions in my event hub and scaling my min and max replicas to this.

A colleague of mine has let me know this is on the roadmap :) https://github.com/microsoft/azure-container-apps/issues/592

This now available in all regions with API version 2024-02-02-preview
